# Modify the receiver of a class that inherits from `Array`

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a class:

```
class MyArray < Array; end
```

I want to define a method that will change an instance of `MyArray` such that:

```
arr = MyArray.new([1,2,3,4]) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.inc # => [2, 3, 4, 5]`
```

Can it be done? How so?

I tried:

```
class MyArray < Array
  def inc
    self.each { |i| i = i + 1 }
  end
end
```

Comment: [Beware subclassing Ruby core classes](https://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyArray < Array
  def inc
    each_index{|i| self[i] += 1}
  end
end

arr = MyArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr.inc # => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or

```
class MyArray < Array
  def inc
    replace(map(&:succ))
  end
end

arr = MyArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr.inc # => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: can you add an explanation? I can see it works, but what `replace` does?

Comment: It replaces the receiver's content with the given argument. When you are not sure, look at the document.

Answer (score 2):

You can write modified elements back to `self` using the regular subscript syntax if you want `#inc` to mutate the MyArray instance in-place:

```
class MyArray
  def inc
    self.each_with_index { |el, idx| self[idx] = el + 1 }
    self
  end
end
```

If you want to return a new instance of `MyArray`, you should use `#map`, which returns a regular `Array`, so wrap it in your class's constructor:

```
class MyArray
  def inc
    self.class.new(self.map { |i| i + 1 })
  end
end
```

Comment: The OP obviously does not "want to return a new instance of `MyArray`".